# operator+ on enum class with non zero starting value

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

I'm need efficient `operator+` for enum class, problem is that enum does not start at zero making calculation difficult.

Here is the enum in question:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

enum class CardRank : std::uint16_t
{
    Two = 2,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace     // = 14
};
```

I want `operator+` for this enum to accept any integral value (up to limit for `short`).

After struggling for some time I come out with the following alogrithm:

```
inline CardRank operator+(const CardRank& rank, const std::uint16_t num)
{
    std::uint16_t need = static_cast<std::uint16_t>(rank) + num;

    if (need < 15)
        return static_cast<CardRank>(need);

    std::uint16_t result = need % 14 + need / 14;

    return static_cast<CardRank>(result > 14 ? result - 13 : result);
}
```

And here is test code:

```
int main()
{
    CardRank rank = CardRank::King;

    // = CardRank::Ace
    std::cout << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(rank + 1) << std::endl;

    // = CardRank::Four
    std::cout << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(rank + 17) << std::endl;

    // = CardRank::Two
    std::cout << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(rank + 41) << std::endl;

    // = CardRank::Ten
    std::cout << static_cast<std::uint16_t>(rank + 114) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Calculation is correct, operator works just fine, but problem is that I just want to add up 2 numbers,
but it turns out that amount of calculation it takes to get the result is not worth having the operator.

Is there some conventional more effective way to make this more simple?

**edit:**
btw, I can't add Ace to beginning and setting it to 1, because of sorting algorithms which sort from highest to smallest card. meaning ace must be above king.

**edit**

Thanks to answers I come out with the following one liner:

```
inline CardRank operator+(const CardRank& rank, const std::uint16_t num)
{
    constexpr std::uint16_t offset = 2;
    constexpr std::uint16_t cards = 13;

    return static_cast<CardRank>((static_cast<std::uint16_t>(rank) - offset + num) % cards + offset);
}
```

Comment: What does `need / 14` in `operator+` means? As I see, it means smth nearly "how many times does `const std::uint16_t num` is bigger that maximum possible value?

Comment: `need % 14` is to get starting value at 0 (which does not exist), `need / 14` tells how many times this starting value was hit. that's how you know for how much the result must be incremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> problem is that enum does not start at zero making calculation difficult.

This is true -- so the first thing to do is to subtract 2, to make it 0 based.  Remember to add the 2 at the end.  This makes it simple.

```
inline CardRank operator+(const CardRank& rank, const std::uint16_t num)
{
    std::uint16_t need = (static_cast<std::uint16_t>(rank) - 2 + num) % 13 + 2;

    return static_cast<CardRank>(need);
}
```